# Why isn't this glFT model loaded through A-Frame displaying on an iPhone browser?

Tags: aframe, gltf

[This example](https://aframe-school-gltf-model.glitch.me/solution.html) displays the model in Chrome on a computer. However, this example does not show anything when it is loaded from either Chrome or Safari on an iPhone 5 (iOS 9.3.1). Does this happen to you too? Why is this happening?

Edit: It works in Safari on an iPhone 6 (iOS 10.2.1), but I still wonder why.

Edit 2: It works in Safari, Firefox and Chrome on an iPhone 5 now; the iOS has been updated to iOS 10.3.2.

Comment: If there are any console messages, they could help to figure out the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Please provide any console logs as the information is so vague I can only speculate.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086800/why-is-not-monster-model-displayed-by-gltfloader-of-three-js-on-ios) thread, loading a glTF model in threeJS on iOS is highly limited by the number of the model bones. 
 If You manage to get the logs working, and You get the *WebGLRenderer: too many bones* issue, it means You will need to change the model.

Also note, that according to the [documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/introduction/vr-headsets-and-webvr-browsers.html), the support of iOS browsers is highly limited, so results may vary from what You get on Your desktop browser.

.